# In MATLAB, how to store Unix stdout in cell array for multi-line commands?

Tags: bash, matlab, unix, system, stdout

I have to run unix code on a remote system that does not have MATLAB. I call it like this

```matlab
% shared key between computers so no password required to type in
ssh_cmd = 'ssh login@ipaddress '; 
for x = 1:nfiles
  cmd = sprintf('calcPosition filename%d',x); 
  % as an example, basically it runs a c++ command 
  % on that computer and I pass in a different filename as an input
  full_cmd = [ssh_cmd, cmd];
  [Status,Message] = system(full_cmd);
  % the stdout is a mix of strings and numbers
  % <code that parses Message and handles errors>
end
```

For a small test this takes about 30 seconds to run. If I set it so that

```matlab
full_cmd = [ssh_cmd, cmd1; cmd2; cmdN]; % obviously not valid syntax here
% do the same thing as above, but no loop
```

it takes about 5 seconds, so most of the time is spent connecting to the other system. But `Message` is the combined stdout of all n files.

I know I can pipe the outputs to separate files, but I'd rather pass it back directly to MATLAB without addition I/O. So is there a way to get the stdout (`Message`) as a cell array (or Unix equivalent) for each separate command? Then I could just loop over the cells of `Message` and the remainder of the function would not need to be changed.

I thought about using an identifier text around each command call as a way to help parse `Message`, e.g.

```matlab
full_cmd = [ssh_cmd; 'echo "begincommand " '; cmd1; 'echo "begincommand " '; cmd2]; % etc
```

But there must be something more elegant than that. Any tips?

Comment: To MATLAB, you are running a single shell command, which produces a single output stream. You approach is pretty good, I don't think you'll find anything better.